# How to POST using httpwebrequest when I need to authenticate and in curl the authentication is done with "username:pass@website.com"?

Tags: c#, curl, httpwebrequest

In brief, in curl I can send post like this:

curl -X POST http://admin:admin@website.com/scriptText  -F 'data here'

So in C# what header or method should I use to mimic this? Is this just basic auth? It doesn't seem to be since when i open the website it uses classic php like post/cookie method to keep track.

I have  a method in C# which lets me log in and keeps me there with cookie but after this i can only use downloadstring() method to GET and not post a "forbidden" data?

Comment: and is uploadata the same as POST?? here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploaddata?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: if i can do it with webclient then it's ok since like i said i use re-written webclient method to keep me logged in, now i just need to know how to send post via webclient...